# Counting number of feature values in ranges in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains multiple positive measurements per patient, like so:

```
    patientID       values
0   patient1        6.2
1   patient1        3.9
2   patient2        7.4
3   patient2        3.4
4   patient2        7.7
5   patient3        9.2
```

I would like to count how many values per patient belong to the following ranges:

- low: 0 - 4
- normal: 4 - 7.8
- high: 7.8 - 20

So I would like to transform the previous dataframe into:

```
    patientID   low  normal  high
0   patient1    1    1       0
1   patient2    1    2       0
2   patient3    0    0       1
```

To do this I have tried to use value_counts with the bins = [0, 4, 7.8, 20], like so:

```py
df.groupby(['patientID'])["values"].value_counts(bins=[0, 4, 7.8, 20], sort=False)
```

Which led to the following output:

```py
patientID    values       
patient1     (-0.001, 4.0]      1
             (4.0, 7.8]        1
             (7.8, 20.0]        0
patient2     (-0.001, 4.0]      1
             (4.0, 7.8]       2
             (7.8, 20.0]        0
patient3     (-0.001, 4.0]      0
             (4.0, 7.8]        0
             (7.8, 20.0]       1
```

So my questions are:

- Is this a correct method to achieve my goal?
- How do I extract the 3 outputs per patients of value_counts to the columns (low, normal, high) to get the dataframe above.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do `cut` with `crosstab`

```
out = pd.crosstab(df.patientID, pd.cut(df['values'],
                                       bins=[0,4,7.8,20],
                                       labels=['low','normal','high']))
#out.reset_index(inplace=True)

Out[5]: 
values     low  normal  high
patientID                   
patient1     1       1     0
patient2     1       2     0
patient3     0       0     1
```